# I need to read a .xlsx file with ruby

Tags: ruby, excel

I'm quite new to ruby and it has amazed me ;) . Nonetheless, I've been having some trouble trying to read some information from an Excel file using ruby.

This is what I have, based on other posts I've read and researched across the web. Thanks in advance.

```
require 'spreadsheet'

doc = Spreadsheet.open('SomeName.xlsx')

sheet = doc.worksheet(0)

value = sheet[10,0]

puts value
```

And the error message I get is as follows: validate! in OLE32 is invalid and a whole bunch of things regarding, initialize, new, open, read, etc.

P.S: I am using ruby 2.1.2 if that makes any difference at all.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the Win32Ole libraries in order to inter-op with Excel in this manner. I have only used it with Outlook and unfortunately I have lost that code (well, no, it's just on my work PC). The Win32Ole libraries are easiest installed by having office installed on your PC. If you don't have that installed, I would recommend you instead use a Jet/Ace driver (if there is one for Ruby), as interop is not recommend even on .NET platforms.

You could use the following code sample to initialize a [Win32Ole](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.2/libdoc/win32ole/rdoc/WIN32OLE.html) instance and open a spreadsheet.

```
require 'win32ole'
xl = WIN32OLE.new('Excel.Application')
wb = xl.Workbooks.Open('c:\file.xls')
```

Unfortunately the Win32Ole rdoc is rather.. sparse. You'll need to look around to find better resources for it. [Here's](http://rubyonwindows.blogspot.co.uk/2007/03/automating-excel-with-ruby.html) one I found that is pretty much the best reference you *will* find. Good luck!

As an aside, I would have been able to give you more help if you provided the exact error and preferably stack-trace you received.